# Where is the "from __future__ import braces" code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

I was wondering what is exactly the code that gets executed on the command:

```
>>> from __future__ import braces
SyntaxError: not a chance
```

Since Python is open-sourced, I opened `C:\Python27\Lib\__future__.py` and looked.
Surprisingly, I found nothing there that handles importing the `braces` module.

So, my question is, where is the code that handles this? What happens when I run that command?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The code is in [future.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/956b8afdaa3e/Python/future.c#l14):

```
future_check_features(PyFutureFeatures *ff, stmt_ty s, const char *filename)
...
  else if (strcmp(feature, "braces") == 0) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_SyntaxError,
        "not a chance");
    PyErr_SyntaxLocation(filename, s->lineno);
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: It's worth explaining a bit more: `from __future__ import foo` is not an import statement, it's a [future statement](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements). The CPython compiler handles this by calling appropriate code from `future.c` first, and _then_ treating it as an `import`. Other compilers will do similar things.

Comment: I changed the link from the dead svn repository to the current hg repository. (This also changed it to link to 3.4 code instead of 2.6, but you can find the [2.7 version](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/future.c#l13) just by replacing the branch tag in the URL with "2.7", or the same for any other version.)

Comment: In case anyone's curious, PyPy 2.1 actually handles `from __future__ import braces` (or a comma-separated list including `braces`) specially, before even getting to the normal `future` statement code, in [`codegen.PythonCodeGenerator.visit_ImportFrom`](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/28108772614ab96ecc6f16ac3a7b8fd0da31e61b/pypy/interpreter/astcompiler/codegen.py?at=default#cl-629).

Comment: Python is a hospitable language:  "Not a chance".

Comment: I'd like to add that it's pretty next-level hilarious that the code to deny braces was written with braces.

Comment: The file on the active github repository: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/future.c